# Retrieve a Value from an array used in a function

Tags: php

Actually I am using PHP to find minimum distance from two places.

I have value of first place defined in two variables(LAT FROM and LON FROM)

The second place is an array of addresses picked up from a database.
A function pick up addresses and find the distance then another function choose the minimum distance.

All works fine I am able to print out the minimum distance but what I am searching for is to know how to print out the address from array corresponding to the minimum distance that function have found.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$latitudeFrom = '45.6686653';
$longitudeFrom = '12.2396675';

$sql = "SELECT address FROM mydatabase;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$datiordinati = [];

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $datiordinati[] = $row["address"];  
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$len=count($datiordinati);
for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){


    // Get JSON results from this request
    $geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($datiordinati[$i]).'&sensor=false');
    $geo = json_decode($geo, true); // Convert the JSON to an array

    if (isset($geo['status']) && ($geo['status'] == 'OK')) {
        $latitudeTo = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; // Latitude
        $longitudeTo = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']; // Longitude
    }

    //Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
    $theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;

    $distance[$i] = ($miles * 1.609344).' km';

}

function getMin($distance) 
{
    $n = count($distance); 
    $min = $distance[0];
    for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) 
       if ($min > $distance[$i])
           $min = $distance[$i];
    return $min;       
}

$finalecho = (getMin($distance));

echo $finalecho; // This print me out the minimum distance 

$conn->close();
```

Comment: You would need to bind the location data to the distance using an associative array. The way you have this written, once you had the min distance, look up the key associated with that distance

Comment: Instead of returning the value from the `getMin()` function, what about returning the index? Then you could use the index to get the distance _and_ the address.

Comment: Looks like `$datiordinati[$i]` is your address

Comment: In your while loop, write something like ---> $datiordinati[$row["address"]] = $distance;

Comment: Justa a thought here, a better approach is to use postGIS, Geographic Information System por postGRES, it would be very easy to do what you are trying to do here. Take a shot at https://postgis.net. Even mySQL has a GIS extension, look at https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/presentations/mysql-57-gis/